# What is generative AI (GenAI) according to this site?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I would like to ask for the definition of the word generative AI (GenAI) according to our community because [some places define somethings different than others](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20generative%20ai%3F). Since we have rules and scopes set to orbit around generative AI, I think we should define it to be solid here for future reference.

What is generative AI (GenAI) according to this site? What is included, and what is not?

**Relate**

[Is Google Translate, the web application, a Generative Artificial Intelligence (GenAI) tool?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/313/is-google-translate-the-web-application-a-generative-artificial-intelligence)

Comment: The boundary is quite blurry: there's predictive text, spelling and grammar checkers, Siri and Alexa, Google Translate, speech-to-text and text-to-speech, optical character recognition, [Github's Copilot](https://github.com/features/copilot), [scigen](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/archive/scigen/), [Cleverbot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleverbot), [Clippy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Assistant), and [proof assistants](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones This question is intended to tackle all of those once and for all. :)

Comment: Reminds me of deep learning vs. neural networks. It's all about finding new names.

Comment: This should be tagged [meta-tag:faq-proposed]. [meta.se] has this tag, and I thing that other child-metas have it. I don't know if it's one of the default tags. Ref. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-proposed

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Do you consider that Google Translate is a GenAI tool? Do you might take a look at [Is Google Translate, the web application, a Generative Artificial Intelligence (GenAI) tool?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/313/12) I just added a bounty :)

Comment: Hahaha!  Don't ask me; I simply don't know.  (:  What Google Translate outputs is certainly derivative, though.

Answer (score 5):

I'll take an initial stab:

- For the "AI" part:

  - Makes use of machine learning techniques (probably gradient descent on a neural network) to model the patterns/structures of a given data set
- For the "generative" part:

  - Outputs new content in a relatively open-ended domain (such as text, images, or audio)
  - Task's output is underdetermined by input, such that there'd be a wide range of acceptable outputs rather than one/few "correct" results

Some examples, including tools mentioned:

| Tool | GenAI? | Reasoning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GPT-3 | ✔ | AI: trained on web text. Generative: text is a broad domain, output of text continuation task is not fully defined by input text |
| Stable Diffusion | ✔ | AI: trained on web images. Generative: images are a broad domain, input prompt doesn't fully define a generated image |
| Gaussian filter | ❌ | Not AI: not trained on data. Not generative: output domain is broad, but output is fully defined by user's input |
| Github Copilot | ✔ | AI: trained on web text, then public Github repos. Generative: code is relatively open domain, and there are many ways to approach a given problem |
| Scigen | ❌ | Not AI: uses a hand-written context-free grammar rather than machine learning from data |
| Clippy | ❌ | Not AI: probably hand-tuned criteria. Not generative: Selects from a set of pre-defined suggestions, rather than an open domain |
| Cleverbot | ❌ | Not generative: assuming output is selected from previous user responses, rather than new text content |
| Google Translate | ❌? | Maybe not generative: output could be considered too tightly defined by the input text |

Comment: Usually, the descriptions of GenAI mention LLM. Are there other models used in GenAI? In other words, if a tool doesn't use an LLM, could it be considered a *GenAI tool*?

Comment: I have forgotten text-to-image artificial intelligence. Does adding columns to your table for LLM and text-to-image make sense? P.S. "Google Translate" should be considered a brand encompassing several products / apps.

Comment: @Wicket "Does adding columns to your table for LLM and text-to-image make sense?" - there is already GPT-3 and Stable Diffusion as examples of an LLM and a text-to-image model respectively. Could possibly add examples for music/audio generation or video generation, though none are widely popular at the moment AFAIK.

Comment: Cleverbot might not generate sentences, but it generates _conversations_. GPT models have word fragments for tokens; where's the line?

Comment: Does GPT with a temperature of 0 not qualify as GenAI?

Comment: @Someone "*Task's* output is under-determined by input" doesn't exclude *models* that can behave deterministically and land on one result, so long as other results would've been equally "correct" a priori - and presumably would be given by other models performing the same task.